# spring batch starter application - fails to start

Tags: spring

I created a starter spring batch application, when I start it I get following error, what am I missing? :

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. [2m2018-04-17
>   16:04:00.262[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m7200[0;39m [2m---[0;39m
>   [2m[           main][0;39m
>   [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
>   *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>   *************************** Description: Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified and no embedded
>   datasource could be auto-configured. Reason: Failed to determine a
>   suitable driver class Action: Consider the following:     If you want an
>   embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
>     If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile
>   you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Here is the POM XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.spring</groupId>    <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>helloworld</name>     <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>         <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->  </parent>

    <properties>        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>      <java.version>1.8</java.version>    </properties>

    <dependencies>      <dependency>            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>      </dependency>

        <dependency>            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>           <scope>test</scope>         </dependency>       <dependency>            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>          <scope>test</scope>         </dependency>   </dependencies>

    <build>         <plugins>           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>           </plugin>       </plugins>  </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```